# How to change the logo depending on page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to set my logo to display a bigger logo for desktops and a smaller image for smaller devices like smartphones...

This is what i've tried until now, but it doesn't works.

Can somebody help me? What's wrong with my code?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load(){
    document.getElementById('logo').src = displaylogo();
}
function displaylogo(){
    if ($(window).width() < 1024) {// code for small viewports
        return "http://i.imgur.com/ozYV740.png"; // small logo
    } 
    else {// code for large viewports
        return "http://i.imgur.com/RMV6Af0.png"; //big logo
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RMV6Af0.png" id="logo" name="logo" title="The original logo is the big logo"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read up on [`@media`](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: no, it's just that code, no jquery but i will try it if using jquery will resolve my problem.

Comment: that code won't work without jquery, its the jquery way to check window width. try `window.innerWidth < 1024` if you really need a JS solution.

Comment: As @arbitter has suggested, use @ media to change how your one single image is sized rather than try and load two separate images.

Comment: Use @media as suggested and make sure you are importing jQuery, the "$" is commonly a shorthand for jQuery, so, in order to make your code at least run.

Comment: i added jquery but the image changes only after page reload...

Comment: jQuery would actually make the task harder. I would take up the @media suggestion. However, if you must use javascript, document.write is a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of you do not use `jquery` Try this in your case :

To work in JS:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {// code for small viewports
    //^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you want to use jquery:

```
function displaylogo() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
        $("#logo").attr("src","http://i.imgur.com/ozYV740.png"); // small logo
    } 
    else {
        $("#logo").attr("src","http://i.imgur.com/RMV6Af0.png"); //big logo
    } 
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    displaylogo();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    displaylogo();
});
```

**I suggest to use `CSS` instead:**

```
<span id="logo"></span>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ozYV740.png) no-repeat; /* small */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    #logo {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: url(http://i.imgur.com/RMV6Af0.png) no-repeat; /* big */
    }
}
```

Comment: @m3tsys I added more info.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using **CSS media queries** to handle how your web page displays on different devices. These queries allow you to apply different styles depending on the width of the user's screen.

For example, to resize your logo for phones, try:

```
/* Desktops (>480px) */
#logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

/* iPhone landscape (480px) */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

Tutorial: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Answer (score 2):

Try using media queries

```
<head>
     <style>
          .logo {
                width: //logo-width
                height : //logo-height
                background-image : url('http://i.imgur.com/RMV6Af0.png');
           }

           @media only screen 
           and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
                .logo {
                    width: //logo-width
                    height : //logo-height
                    background-image : url('http://i.imgur.com/ozYV740.png');
                }
           }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo">
</div>
</body>
```